# Pascal adding whitespace to file typed

Tags: pascal

I am trying to write something to a file but pascal adds a bunch of whitespaces between each record's value and also puts 2 records on one line.

The first file is just a list of strings.
The second file (the one I create through the program) should have title and description.

How can I get rid of the whitespaces pascal is adding?

```
program Wiki;
  {$mode objfpc}

TYPE wiki=record
    title:string;
    description:string;

  end;
var
  f:text ;
  g:file of wiki ;
  row:wiki;
  fileName: string;
  oldFileName:string;

begin
  writeln('Old file name:');
  readln(oldFileName);
  ASSIGN(f,oldFileName);
  RESET(f);
  writeln('New file name:');
  readln(fileName);
  ASSIGN(g,fileName);
  REWRITE(g);

REPEAT
  Readln(f,row.title);
  writeln('give a description:');
  Writeln(row.title);
  Readln(row.description);
  Write(g,row)

until EOF(f);

  CLOSE(f);
  CLOSE(g);
  writeln;
  writeln('press enter to close.');
  readln();
end.
```

Comment: Why -1? This is more than a valid question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `objfpc` mode without `{$H+}`, I guess that `row.description` is a fixed size Turbo Pascal style `ShortString`. It is 255 characters long, and that is probably why you get all that whitespace.

Rather write the output file as a text file:

```
var
  f: Text;
  g: Text;
```

and:

```
Writeln(g, row.title, ';', row.description);
```

That should produce text output like:

```
Finding Nemo;The adventures of two fish trying to find the lost son of one of them
Toy Story;The adventures of a merry bunch of toys
```

etc.